# Is Divergence without a dot product symbol a gradient on vector?

Tags: inner-products, fluid-dynamics, divergence-operator, gradient-flows

Divergence operating on a vector field ($\mathbf{u}=[u, v, w]\in\mathbb{R}^3$) outputs a scalar field:

$\nabla\cdot \mathbf{u} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial w}{\partial z}\in \mathbb{R}$

If there is no dot product symbol $\cdot$, is it a gradient on a vector?

$\nabla \mathbf{u} = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial w}{\partial x}\\\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial w}{\partial y}\\\frac{\partial u}{\partial z} & \frac{\partial v}{\partial z} & \frac{\partial w}{\partial z}
\end{bmatrix}\in \mathbb{R}^{3 \times 3}$

It seems the dot product symbol is really really important - should not make a typo by mistake.

Comment: Yes it is a matrix, but most commonly the transpose of what you wrote.

Comment: check this wiki page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates

the table will show you all possible del formulas.

Comment: @Funktorality Awesome, thanks

Comment: @knight5478 Thanks, it's quiet handy